# R: icc{irr}: Attempting one-way model with multiple ratings per rater per subject

Tags: r

I haven't found my particular scenario in any of the other threads online regarding the ICC{psych} / icc{irr} functions.

I am trying to find interrater reliability based on data that has columns for subject, rater, and then multiple rating columns. (From what I'm gathering, most people work with data that has simply raters as columns, subjects as rows, and the single rating in the cell.)

Data sample:

[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbd3U.png)

Here is the code I have tried:

```
icc(data.pers.icc[,5],model="oneway",type="consistency",unit="average",r0=0,conf.level=0.95)

icc(data.pers.icc[,c(1,2,5)],model="oneway",type="consistency",unit="average",conf.level=0.95)
```

I understand why the second line of code gives me an error; the formula is not designed to take each column as a separate data point, but as a separate rater. 
But I do not understand why the first line does not work. It gives me an answer of NA:

```
Average Score Intraclass Correlation

Model: oneway 
Type : consistency 

Subjects = 48 
Raters = 1 
ICC(1) = NA

F-Test, H0: r0 = 0 ; H1: r0 > 0 
F(47,0) = NA , p = NA 

95%-Confidence Interval for ICC Population Values:
NA < ICC < NA
```

I have also tried including the rating and subject columns, but this latter reads as an ICC(2) and also gives me NA as the answer.

Even if this worked, I would still have to repeat the process for every column, so I have extracted factor scores and added to the column that I could use instead, but am stuck because I have no idea how to run even a single column through this function.

P.S. I have also tried ICC:

```
ICC(data.pers.icc[,c(35)],alpha=0.05)
```

but it gives me this error:

ICC error1:

[image: ICC error1]

If I include the subject and rating columns, it produces another error message that says: 'contrasts can only be applied to factors with 2 or more levels'.

Would appreciate any help! I have a second, much larger dataframe to do this with, as well. Sorry for my newbie approach to R and stats.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the first argument of the `icc` function should be "n*m matrix or dataframe, n subjects m raters.". This means that columns are raters and rows are subjects.
If there is just one column (as in `icc(data.pers.icc[,5],model="oneway",type="consistency",unit="average",r0=0,conf.level=0.95)`), there is just one rater. Therefore icc can't be computed.

Concerning your second example `(icc(data.pers.icc[,c(1,2,5)],model="oneway",type="consistency",unit="average",conf.level=0.95)`): the first column contains names of subjects which is wrong. All columns have to be numeric. Moreover, you should treat your traits separately.

The correct input for the Trait1 should look like this:

```
  Adam LiaoBo Fatima Maria
A  5.5     NA     NA    NA
B  5.0      4     NA    NA
D   NA     NA      7    NA
E  4.0      7     NA    NA
F  1.0     NA      2     4
```

However, if you put this to the icc function, it will return NA as well. Experimentally, I found out that this function is not able to deal with that many NA values.However, function `ICC` from the `psych` package is somehow able to deal with that NAs when you specify, that it should use all cases and not just complete ones:

So you can compute icc like this:

```
   my_data <-cbind(
   c(5.5, 5, NA, 4, 1), #Adam
   c(NA, 4, NA, 7, NA), #LiaoBo
   c(NA, NA, 7, NA, 2), #Fatima
   c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4)) #Maria

ICC(my_data,missing=F)
```

which will give you following output:

```
Call: ICC(x = my_data, missing = F)

Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type  ICC   F df1 df2     p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 0.26 2.4   4  15 0.096       -0.10        0.83
Single_random_raters     ICC2 0.11 1.5   4  12 0.277       -0.22        0.77
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3 0.10 1.5   4  12 0.277       -0.19        0.75
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k 0.58 2.4   4  15 0.096       -0.58        0.95
Average_random_raters   ICC2k 0.34 1.5   4  12 0.277       -2.50        0.93
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k 0.31 1.5   4  12 0.277       -1.84        0.92

 Number of subjects = 5     Number of Judges =  4
```

Now, you`ll just select the correct one.

However, I have read that icc index can be used either for fully-crossed design (i.e.: when all raters provides ratings for all subjects) or when a new set of raters is randomly selected for each subject. So icc might isn't the best choice for your dataset.

Index which is able to deal better with NAs is called Krippendorff's alpha and it is available in the `irr` package too. The only additional argument to specify is type of your data (argument: `method = ("nominal","ordinal","interval","ratio")`). (I do not know your data, so you`ll might decide for other method then I used bellow.)

Krippendorff's alpha for the Trait1 can be computed like this:

```
    kripp.alpha(t(my_data) ,"ratio")
```

will give you

```
    Krippendorff's alpha

 Subjects = 5 
   Raters = 4 
    alpha = -0.167
```

This means that your inter-rater reliability is slightly worse than expected by chance. This result is very different from one obtained by ICC. However I don`t think any index  would be meaningful for such a small matrix with that many missing values.

Generally, be aware of confusing subjects and raters. For example for this index I had to transform my matrix (function `t`).

If you want to know more about icc, Krippendorff's alpha and inter-rater reliability in general, I  recommend you following articles which are understandable even for non-statisticians:

- Hallgren, K. A. (2012). Computing Inter-Rater Reliability for
  Observational Data: An Overview and Tutorial. Tutorials in
  Quantitative Methods for Psychology, 8(1), 23–34.
  http://doi.org/10.20982/tqmp.08.1.p023
- Koo, T. K., & Li, M. Y. (2016). A Guideline of Selecting and
  Reporting Intraclass Correlation Coefficients for Reliability
  Research. Journal of Chiropractic Medicine, 15(2), 155–163.
  http://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcm.2016.02.012
- Stemler, S. E., & Tsai, J. (2008). Best practices in interrater
  reliability: Three common approaches. Best practices in quantitative 
  methods. http://doi.org/10.4135/9781412995627.d5
- Feng, G. C. (2015). Mistakes and how to avoid mistakes in using
  intercoder reliability indices. Methodology, 11(1), 13–22.
  http://doi.org/10.1027/1614-2241/a000086
- http://digital-activism.org/2013/05/picking-the-best-intercoder-reliability-statistic-for-your-digital-activism-content-analysis/

P.S.: I want you know, I'm not a statistician. I've just spent few days reading articles about indexes and dealing with similar problems as you.

Comment: Hi Kamila, Seeing you prowess in ICC can you please help my query as well 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129100/calculate-intraclass-coefficient-for-all-permutation-of-variable-in-r